# excel vba enter key run macro

Tags: vba, excel

I'm sure this must be simple but for the life of me I can't find how to do it

How do I detect that the enter key has been pressed on a particular range of cell

I have a group of merged cells ($H$9:$K$13) which is basically a box which the user enters a number. I want to run a macro once the user presses enter (on the keyboard NOT the num keypad)

I cant find any examples on this. I can find example on doing this from a text box but not from a cell

I have tried Application.onkeys which works on key combinations but not on the enter key (it says tilde for enter key and ENTER for num pad but neither work)

Comment: Why do you want to differentiate the number keypad enter vs. normal enter key?

Answer (score 0):

Do you surely want to detect the press event of ENTER keys?

How do you think, if users used tab key to change the input of certain cells you noted in your post. Or selection range was changed because of mouse click leaving values in cell changed.

I'm little confused, because using [Workbook.SheetChange Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196611%28v=office.15%29.aspx) you can run procedures for your purpose. Of course you can check the range changed was in the range you noted or not, in this event procedure using argument Target.

Comment: I check the event in the worksheet event to clear the range when it is focused i want it so you can type a number and then hit return when it looses focus Ie after you typed the number press enter. there are only two ranges on the sheet you type a number in either depending on which column you want to search on