# Application.OnKey Fails to Reset Properly

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to help another user in this forum ([reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48512147/run-a-macro-in-excel-2010-using-enter-key-whether-worksheet-has-changed-or-not/48512820#48512820)).  The goal is to use the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key on the numeric keypad to trigger a macro rather than use the Worksheet_Change event macro for the same purpose.
Before anything is run, both <kbd>Enter</kbd> keys work identically.  You type stuff in, touch either key, the material gets placed in the cell and `Selection` moves downward.  If you just pump either key, `Selection` just moves downward.

In a standard module I put:

```
Sub NumericEnter()
    Application.OnKey "{ENTER}", "InsertIntoTables"
End Sub
```

and

```
Sub InsertIntoTables()
    MsgBox "Inserting"
End Sub
```

After I run `NumericEnter()`, the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key on the numeric keypad calls the proper macro each time it is touched.  The normal <kbd>Enter</kbd> key is not affected.

I then tried to restore the numeric <kbd>Enter</kbd> key by running:

```
Sub ClearEnter()
    Application.OnKey "{ENTER}", ""
End Sub
```

The numeric <kbd>Enter</kbd> key partially reverts to its original behavior.  It no longer calls the macro; it allows data entry into cell, **but it does not move `Selection` at all!**  *(the regular enter key still behaves normally)*

I have no idea of what I have missed.

**What I have looked at:**

- The normal enter key, the ARROW keys, and the TAB key work just fine at changing `Selection`
- Mouse clicking works fine at changing `Selection`
- the values of `Application.MoveAfterReturn` and `Application.MoveAfterReturnDirection` look fine as well.

Comment: Have you tried mapping to `vbNullString` instead of `""`? Might not work, but maybe receiving a null string pointer can hint `OnKey` that we're trying to *remove* a macro (as opposed to *remap*) - just thinking out loud, haven't tried it

Comment: @Mat'sMug  Thanks for the suggestion............sadly, the behavior is the same.

Comment: Interestingly, it looks like [this post](https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s4/win012.htm) suggests you're doing everything right. The plot thickens...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using just

```
Application.OnKey "{ENTER}"
```

with no second argument seems to clear the macro mapping and return the default key action (Excel 2013)

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/application-onkey-method-excel

```
expression.OnKey( Key , Procedure )
```

The description for the `Procedure` parameter has this:

> A string indicating the name of the procedure to be run. **If Procedure
>   is "" (empty text), nothing happens when Key is pressed.** This form of
>   OnKey changes the normal result of keystrokes in Microsoft Excel. **If
>   Procedure is omitted, Key reverts to its normal result in Microsoft
>   Excel**, and any special key assignments made with previous OnKey
>   methods are cleared.

Comment: @Tim Williams As the "other user" mentioned in line one, I super appreciate the help!