# Setting up procedures in Excel for hotkey use

Tags: excel, vba

I want the procedure below embedded in a macro-enabled Excel (xlsm) file.

```
Sub SaveWorksheetsAsCSV()
Dim WS As Excel.Worksheet
Dim CurrentWorkbook As String
Dim CurrentFormat As Long
CurrentWorkbook = ThisWorkbook.FullName
CurrentFormat = ThisWorkbook.FileFormat
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
For Each WS In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    WS.Copy
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=CurrentWorkbook & "-" & WS.Name & ".csv", FileFormat:=xlCSV
    ActiveWorkbook.Close savechanges:=False
    ThisWorkbook.Activate
Next
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

I want the procedure to be assigned to a hotkey (Shift+Alt+S), so I also embed this procedure.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
Application.OnKey "+%s", "SaveWorksheetsAsCSV"
End Sub
```

I put both of these procedures in the “ThisWorkbook” of the “Microsoft Excel Objects” folder, because I want the hotkey’ed save as CSV procedure to be usable from any sheet after the file is opened.

I can bring up the macro list with Alt+F8 and run ThisWorkbook.SaveWorksheetsAsCSV and all sheets are saved as CSV files as expected. But when I use the hotkey (Shift+Alt+S), I get the error message “Cannot run macro...” I'm fairly certain it’s not a permission thing, for testing I’ve turn on “Enable all macros” in Macro Security settings.

Can someone help me set this up properly? This XLSM file will be used as a template that people will copy and modify and then convert to CSV for import into another tool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Put the procedure `Sub SaveWorksheetsAsCSV()` in a module.
2. Write the word `Public` in front of it `Public Sub SaveWorksheetsAsCSV()`
3. Make sure that you write it only **once**.

Then it will work from any worksheet, independently. 
This is quite ok, let it stay:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Application.OnKey "+%s", "SaveWorksheetsAsCSV"
End Sub
```

Depending on the way how you (user users) use Excel, it might be a good idea to write a similar `Workbook_Close()` procedure:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Close()
    Application.OnKey "+%s"
End Sub
```

Comment: Writing a `Workbook_Close()` Routine, it seems to be preferable to omit the second `OnKey` parameter completely to revert the key to its normal result - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48552588/application-onkey-fails-to-reset-properly

Comment: @T.M. - true. And if you take a look here - https://github.com/Vitosh/VBA_personal/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=onkey&type=, you would see how much I have learned between March and June 2017 :D

Answer (score 1):

Set the `Application.MacroOptions`
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/application-macrooptions-method-excel

```
Public Sub SetMacroOptions()

    Application.MacroOptions _
        Macro:="SaveWorksheetsAsCSV", _
        Description:="Saves the sheet as a CSV", _
        HasShortCutKey:=True, _
        ShortcutKey:="s"

End Sub
```

Not sure if you can set it with *Alt* using this method though.